# Cut-off of milliseconds in as.character.POSIXt

Tags: r, rounding, posixct

can someone explain to me what happens here? Is this a bug in R or intended behavior?

First, I create a sequence of POSIXct with a stepwith of 0.1 secs:

```
options(digits.secs = 6, digits = 6)
test <- as.POSIXct("2018-08-31 14:15:16.000000")
test_seq <- seq(test, test + 1, by = 1/10)
```

Calling `format` with the millisecond conversion specification gives the intended result (even though there is a small representation error)

```
## this works as intended
format(test_seq, "%F %T.%OS")
```

Gives Output:

```
 [1] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.000000" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.099999" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.200000" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.299999"
 [5] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.400000" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.500000" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.599999" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.700000"
 [9] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.799999" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.900000" "2018-08-31 14:15:17.17.000000"
```

However, if I use `as.character` the milliseconds seemingly get just cut-off after one digit (even though I specified `digits.secs = 6` in `options`). Due to this behavior and the misrepresentation error the resulting string is incorrect:

```
as.character(test_seq)
```

Gives output (note that every two strings are equal):

```
 [1] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.0" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.0" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.2" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.2" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.4" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.5"
 [7] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.5" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.7" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.7" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.9" "2018-08-31 14:15:17.0"
```

For further clarification:

```
as.character(as.POSIXct("2018-08-31 14:15:16.123456"))
```

displays all millisecond digits correctly (does not cut-off). Thus, I think that in the former case it decides that there is only one significant millisecond digit (which is correct) and then cuts the result after one digit (which is incorrect due to the misrepresentation)

Answer (score 0):

`as.character.POSIXt` takes a `format=` argument.

If you don't call it with a `format=`, you get the default which cuts at tenths-of-seconds (because of significant digits, as per your edit). Instead, try:

```
as.character(test_seq, format = "%F %T.%OS")
#[1] "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.000000" "2018-08-31 14:15:16.16.099999" ...
```

In fact, `as.character.POSIXt()` is just a wrapper around `format()`

```
as.character.POSIXt
#function (x, ...) 
#format(x, ...)
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

so `format(test_seq)` will give you the same as `as.character(test_seq)` *sans* format.

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct: as.character(as.POSIXct("2018-08-31 14:15:16.123456")) displays all digits correctly (after setting digits.secs=6 like above)